# com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

The Android application which was working well previously, after upgrading my Android Studio version to 3.4.1 the same source code that worked fine now throws some unexpected errors.

Ionic Info

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4 ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.4 
ios-sim    : 8.0.1 
Node       : v10.7.0
npm        : 6.9.2 
OS         : macOS
Xcode      : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

List of plugins used

```
cordova plugin ls
cordova-fabric-plugin 1.1.14-dev "cordova-fabric-plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-document-viewer 0.9.10 "SitewaertsDocumentViewer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-mixpanel 4.6.0 "Mixpanel"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

The error terminal throws while building the app is below.

```
:app:processDebugResources
/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.aar/bfa93912b1b925ab573ea67bb72d9d80/res/values/values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.aar/bfa93912b1b925ab573ea67bb72d9d80/res/values/values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/macuser/Desktop/myProject/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/macuser/Desktop/myProject/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s
 FAILED
33 actionable tasks: 29 executed, 4 up-to-date
/Users/macuser/Desktop/myProject/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.aar/bfa93912b1b925ab573ea67bb72d9d80/res/values/values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-27.1.1.aar/bfa93912b1b925ab573ea67bb72d9d80/res/values/values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/macuser/Desktop/myProject/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/macuser/Desktop/myProject/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProces
s.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running Cordova build android (exit code 1).



expected Output: Build successful  

Error messages: BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s.
```